# setState is not changing view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component "BulkActionPanel" that renders some buttons. Buttons are enabled or disabled based on the array property "selectedJobIds" passed as a props from its parent component "Grid". Precisely, if length of props "selectedJobIds" is greater than 0 then buttons are enabled else they are disabled.

I have a callback on "onClick" of all the buttons inside BulkActionPanel component, that sets the selectedJobIds to '0' by calling actionCreator "this.props.removeSelectedJobIds([rowData.id])" and it ensures that buttons are disabled.

Since action creator takes a lot of time (does heavy processing on grid), I am maintaining a local state "disable" inside BulkActionPanel to ensure button gets disabled first and then selectedJobIds state is updated in redux store.

I wrote the code below but buttons are not getting disabled until action creator " this.props.removeSelectedJobIds([rowData.id]);" finishes.

```
export default class Grid extends Component {
     render() {
         <BulkActionPanel
              actions={this.bulkActions}
              selectedJobIds={this.getFromConfig(this.props.config, [SELECTED_ROWS_PATH_IN_GRID_CONFIG])}
         />
         <SlickGrid/>
     }
}


export default class BulkActionPanel extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            disable: true
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.selectedJobIds && nextProps.selectedJobIds.length > 0){
            this.setState({disable:false});
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.selectedJobIds !== undefined && nextProps.selectedJobIds.length
    }

    @autobind
    onActionButtonClick(action) {
            this.setState({disable:true}
            , () => {
                    // Action creator that takes a lots of time
                    this.props.removeSelectedJobIds([rowData.id]);

                }
            );
    }

    @autobind
    renderFrequentActions() {
        return this.props.actions.frequentActions.map((frequentAction) => (
            <button
              className="btn btn-default"
              key={frequentAction.DISPLAY_NAME}
              onClick={() => this.onActionButtonClick(frequentAction)}
              disabled={this.state.disable}
            >
                {frequentAction.DISPLAY_NAME}
            </button>
            ));
    }

    render() {
        const frequentActions = this.renderFrequentActions();

        return (
            <div className="btn-toolbar bulk-action-panel">
                {frequentActions}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Does it has something to do with parent child relation of Grid and BulkActionPanel component? Leads here is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the problem persist if you just call the functions one after the other, rather than having `removeSelectedJobIds` a callback of `setState`?

Comment: try removing `shouldComponentUpdate` and see if help, looks like your prevent updates if length of selectedJobIds is 0

Comment: Jayce44 yes I did try that but it didnt work, callback is needed to ensure state gets updated before any further processing

Comment: thedude shouldComponentUpdate is working as expected

Comment: @Jayce444 please note that "removeSelectedJobIds" takes a lots of time hence I am using a setState callback.

Answer (score -1):

I think your component is not passing this

```
if(nextProps.selectedJobIds && nextProps.selectedJobIds.length > 0){
    this.setState({disable:false});
}
```

you have in your componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: It is passing this, I checked by putting a debugged on render

Answer (score -1):

if callback from removeSelectedJobIds isn't fired, state won't be changed, try set state of button like you did, and use reducer to dispatch action when removeSelectedJobIds finished, catch that action and rerender or change what you need.

OR

Use reducer for everything. onclick call actin type that let's you know data in table is rendering, use initail state in reducer to disable btn, when data in table finishes calucating fire action in reducer that send new data to component state

Comment: post your reducer it will help